# How to get the temperature using hddtemp for a Samsung SSD/NVMe in Thinkpad T480

Tags: ssd, thinkpad, temperature, nvme

I try to read my SSD/NVMe temp in my T480. Therefore I want to use `hddtemp` as it runs as daemon in the background.

Debugging `hddtemp` I get the following:

```
sudo hddtemp /dev/nvme0n1 --debug
```

```
ERROR: /dev/nvme0n1: can't determine bus type (or this bus type is
unknown)

If one of the field value seems to match the temperature, be sure to
read the hddtemp man page before sending a report (section REPORT).
Thanks.
```

Using `S.M.A.R.T` I can read its temperature:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
```

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-000L7
[...]

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
[...]
Temperature:                        40 Celsius
[...]
```

Any clue how to get `hddtemp` get running?

Comment: smartctl doesn't fully support nvme yet. You also use `nvme-cli`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038701/how-do-i-check-system-health/1038711#1038711

Answer (score 4):

From:

- [How do I check system health?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038701/how-do-i-check-system-health/1038711#1038711)

#### NVMe PCIe M.2 Gen 3.0 x 4 (or 2) SSD

If you have an SSD they're life span is measured in trillions of writes. Your **SMART** utility already measures SSD life but not for NVMe SSDs. For that you need `nvme-cli`. To install it use:

```
sudo apt install nvme-cli
```

Next gather information available from SSD:

```
$ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 40 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 12,539,332
data_units_written                  : 10,623,582
host_read_commands                  : 281,194,884
host_write_commands                 : 96,528,713
controller_busy_time                : 672
power_cycles                        : 1,677
power_on_hours                      : 687
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 105
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 279
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 40 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 51 C
Temperature Sensor 3                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 4                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 5                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 6                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 7                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 8                : 0 C
```

The most important field is `Percentage used` which shows as 0%. This isn't disk usage percent but **life used** percent. I've had this drive since October 2017 and now it's December 2018. As soon as `Percentage used` hits 1% I can multiply the number of months I've owned it by 100 to find out when it will die. At the current rate I can say the drive will live 100+ years. Of course it will be obsolete in ten years anyway.

Notice the **temperature** report.