# files created then deleted at every second in tmp directory

Tags: files, tmp

By mistake I noticed that in /tmp directory are continuously created some files then immediately deleted. Using a succession of `ls -l /tmp` I managed to catch the created files:

```
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:37  YlOmPA069G
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:37  l74jZzbcs6
```

or another example:

```
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:44  AwVhWakvQ_
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:44  RpRGl__cIM
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:44  S0e72nkpBl
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Apr  2 19:44  emxIQQMSy2
```

It's about Ubuntu 18.10 with 4.18.0-16-generic. This is an almost fresh install: I added some server software (nginx, mysql, php7.2-fpm) but even with those closed the problem persists.

What are the files created and why? 
How would I stop this behaviour? a very **undesirable** one on a **SSD**

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The question is about when not having /tmp in RAM (no [tmpfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tmpfs)).
The guilty software is *x2goserver.service* otherwise a *must have* one.

Comment: "a very undesirable one on a SSD" explain this please? You don't have /tmp as a tmpfs? why not? why would files in memory damage a ssd?

Comment: /tmp may not necessarily be tmpfs, so it's a valid question

Comment: Yes, it would be undesirable on a SSD, at least if the directory metadata actually got written back to disk instead of just staying hot in cache.  This is why `/tmp` is normally on tmpfs (a ramdisk filesystem that uses the pagecache as its backing store); you tagged your question with the [tag:tmpfs], so your comments about SSDs seem out of place.

Comment: @OP really tangential here, but how's your experience with X2Go going so far?

Comment: great - it’s a must have

Comment: @ColinIanKing not when you tag it as 'tmpfs'

Comment: Post your `df`; this question may quickly become how to set up `tmpfs` properly.

Comment: guys, the *tmpfs* tag was a mistake I solved (I removed it). Considering the relation to the topic I'm not totally sure that *tmpfs* is indeed a mistake but also doesn't hurt me to remove it so I did it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure that the statement "`/tmp` is normally on tmpfs" is valid for a normal Ubuntu user - Just using the default Ubuntu install, `/tmp` is on disk and the OP would need to create the appropriate fstab entries to put it into a tmpfs

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Oh, when did that change?  I thought Ubuntu at least used to default to putting /tmp on tmpfs.  (I've been using Arch Linux for my latest desktop, which I'm pretty sure did default to tmpfs.  It's been a while since I installed Ubuntu, so I might just have been forgetting having to edit fstab for that along with NFS and so on.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Can't say - I've only been using Ubuntu since 12.04 - but if you boot from a live USB, and choose "Erase disk and install" then the /tmp directory is on disk.

Comment: The file is generated by Firefox. Close Firefox and the file will vanish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest installing and running fnotifystat to detect the process that is creating these files:

```
sudo apt-get install fnotifystat
sudo fnotifystat -i /tmp
```

You will see process that is doing the open/close/read/write activity something like the following:

```
Total   Open  Close   Read  Write   PID  Process         Pathname
  3.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    1.0   5748 firefox         /tmp/cubeb-shm-5748-input (deleted)
  2.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    1.0  18135 firefox         /tmp/cubeb-shm-5748-output (deleted)
  1.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   5748 firefox         /tmp/cubeb-shm-5748-output (deleted)
```

Comment: Postscript: I'm the author of this tool: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/fnotifystat/

Comment: And you are also the first who answered the question (though no longer visible that). It's a good tool by the way.

Comment: +1 for a very handy utility. Timely too as I can use it to monitor my next project of creating `/tmp/...` files for IPC between daemon and user space instead of more complicated DBUS.

Answer (score 8):

#### Determine which program/process is touching files

You can use tools such as `lsof` to determine which processes and binaries are touching/opening which files.  This could become troublesome if the files change frequently, so you can instead set up a watch to notify you:

```bsh
$ sudo fnotifystat -i /tmp
```

Sometimes, simply looking at the user or group owner gives you a good hint (ie: `ls -lsha`).

---

#### Put `/tmp` into RAM instead of disk

If you desire, you can put your `/tmp` directory into RAM.  You will have to determine if this is a smart move based on available RAM, as well as the size and frequency of read/writes.

```bsh
$ sudo vim /etc/fstab

...
# tmpfs in RAM
tmpfs         /tmp         tmpfs         defaults,noatime,mode=1777      0 0
...
```

```bsh
$ sudo mount /tmp
$ mount | grep tmp # Check /tmp is in RAM
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noatime)
```

If you have enough RAM, this can be considered a very good thing to do for both the longevity of your SSD, as well as the speed of your system.  You can even accomplish this with smaller amounts of RAM if you tweak `tmpreaper` (sometimes `tmpwatch`) to be more aggressive.

Answer (score 6):

> very undesirable one on a SSD

You tagged your question with [tmpfs](/questions/tagged/tmpfs), so it is not quite clear to me how this relates to SSD at all. Tmpfs is an in-memory (or more precisely, in-block-cache) filesystem, so it will never hit a physical disk.

Furthermore, even if you had a physical backing store for your `/tmp` filesystem, unless you have a system with only a couple of kilobytes of RAM, those short-lived files will never hit the disk, all operations will happen in the cache.

So, in other words, there is nothing to worry about since you are using tmpfs, and if you weren't, there still would be nothing to worry about.

Comment: I keep the /tmp in RAM so by mistake I tagged also with my current fs type (tmpfs). I removed it now but I find you're answer useful too so 1 up from me.

Comment: @adrhc: If your `/tmp` is in RAM, then it has nothing whatsoever to do with your SSD, so it is neither desirable nor undesirable but actually completely unrelated.

Comment: I agree but the question is about when not having /tmp in RAM. It just happened that I had /tmp in RAM; still, the problem intrigued me.

Answer (score 0):

People worry too much about SSD write endurance.  Assuming that creating and deleting an empty file writes 24 kB every second, and using the 150 TBW spec for the popular Samsung 860 EVO 250 GB, wear-out takes 193 years!

(150 * 10 ^ 12) / ((2 * 3 * 4 * 1024) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25) = 193

For ext4 filesystems, use "tune2fs -l" to find Lifetime writes.  Or, use "smartctl -a" and look for Total_LBAs_Written.  I always find the SSD has lots of life left.

Comment: The question is "What are the files created and why? How would I stop this behaviour?", how does your "answer" fit to the question?

Comment: Though not directly answering the question I find this information useful too though not very precise related to how to use those commands. E.g. with tune2fs I get `tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme0n1`.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong `/dev/nvme0...` name:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

The right format is:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p6
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem volume name:   New_Ubuntu_16.04
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          b40b3925-70ef-447f-923e-1b05467c00e7
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              2953920
Block count:              11829504
Reserved block count:     534012
Free blocks:              6883701
Free inodes:              2277641
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1021
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Aug  2 20:14:59 2018
Last mount time:          Thu Apr  4 21:05:29 2019
Last write time:          Thu Feb 14 21:36:27 2019
Mount count:              377
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Aug  2 20:14:59 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          4920 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1308352
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      a179d56c-6c68-468c-8070-ffa5bb7cd973
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

As far as [lifetime of NVMe SSD](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038711/307523) goes:

```
$ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 38 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 22,351,778
data_units_written                  : 14,667,833
host_read_commands                  : 379,349,109
host_write_commands                 : 127,359,479
controller_busy_time                : 952
power_cycles                        : 1,925
power_on_hours                      : 1,016
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 113
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 598
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 38 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 49 C
Temperature Sensor 3                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 4                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 5                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 6                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 7                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 8                : 0 C
```

The key line here is:

```
percentage_used                     : 0%
```

After 18 months of use the SSD percentage use is 0%. If after 3 years of use it hits 1% then I know the SSD will last 300 years.

Obviously this answer would not fit into comment section to reply to other comments.

Comment: What part from the tune2fs output relates to the SSD's life time?

Comment: @adrhc I was showing the correct way of calling `tune2fs` in response to your comment on [Fraser Gunn's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132503/307523) showing an error message.