# First time crontab. Is this viable?

Tags: cron

I tried to do some "coding" myself and this is what I came up with:

```
00 02 * * 1,3,5     sudo shutdown -r
@midnight           sudo apt-get update && sleep 60 && apt-get upgrade -y
@reboot             sleep 60 && sudo netplan apply && sleep 15 && sudo omd start website
```

It is crucial that both the network and the website are both up and running after the reboot. Also, is the `1,3,5` part viable? Would this restart the machine on Mo, We and Fr?
And would it be good/smart to schedule a restart after the update/upgrade?

Comment: I have no affiliation with the website, but I use this site often to validate my crontab "preferences": https://crontab.guru/

Comment: @dan one of my many bookmarks ;-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I know what each line does, but what is your objective? Why omd isn't a service? What's the point of restarting the system? Unattended upgrades upgrades your system reliably for security upgrades (or other upgrades if you  set it to).

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you use `systemd` timers instead. Learning `crontab` in 2021 is of limited usefulness, unless it’s a computer history museum project of some sort.

Answer (score 8):

A general comment: Instead of using `sudo` in the `user` crontab, consider putting these commands in the `root` crontab, so they can run without sudo.

As for your 3 crontab lines:

> @midnight          sudo apt-get update && sleep 60 && apt-get upgrade -y

It's perfectly viable to do `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade -y` in this way. *(Not intended for a production server, and under the condition that you understand the implications of unattended upgrades.)*

> 00 02 * * 1,3,5     sudo shutdown -r

I wouldn't think it's necessary to reboot 3 times a week. I myself use this very simple reboot script: (called `auto-reboot.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -f /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs ]] && reboot
```

So I run this script with cron weekly, after my upgrade and cleanup script. It only reboots if the machine needs to be rebooted (if `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` exist). *(Again, this is not intended for a production server.)*

> @reboot             sleep 60 && sudo netplan apply && sleep 15 && sudo omd start website

I don't understand why you would need to run `netplan apply` on reboot.

Also, a more reliable way to start a service that is depending on another service or condition (e.g. network) is to create a systemd `.service` to do the job. There are several tutorials for this ([1](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux), [2](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/)), that I would recommend you take a look at.

Comment: And in case someone wants to know: we wrote these 2 independent of eachother and indeed largely wrote the same things. Made me smile :-) I can't be the only upvotee :(

Comment: Yeah same for me - generally the same message, but cover some different subtle nuances. ;-)

Comment: Oh wow okay thank you very much...
The Problem with the machine is that it keeps freezing after about 5 days uptime. And i already had it 3 times that the network settings were off after the reboot and I had to reapply the netplan.
So I thought I might just restart the PC periodically since the hardware most likely isn't capable of running 24/7.

Comment: @SomeDude that sounds like you have a serious problem somewhere. My _laptop_ is capable of running 24/7, I can't imagine your hardware cannot. Check your RAM and swap usage or ask a new question and we can help you investigate.

Comment: @terdon I used a decommissioned  [HP Prodesk 600 G3 mini](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05364047) with an i5-7500T and 8GB DDR4 which is 4 years old now... I could step it up and create a VM on our live servers but for testing purposes I used this PC. To get familiar with the software and whatnot. Is there an easy way to check if it's a hardware problem?

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038701/how-do-i-check-system-health) is a thread with some info on hardware testing. Also, try and search for the tag [hardware-test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware-test).

Answer (score 8):

Nope.

- You do not use sudo in cron. use root crontab if you need access to commands needing root
- Always use absolute paths when in cron.
- And you should not upgrade a --production-- server unattended; you do that manually. Cool if it is a desktop or if it is a testing/staging server. My personal experience is from using CLOUD servers: *anything going wrong during a reboot is fatal*.

But if you really want to do this I would add the following 3 ...

- add logging to the "apt" commands
- add a method to mail you what was printed during the apt commands.
- before the "apt" you really should also make a full system backup that is stored outside of the server. When the update/upgrade goes wrong and it affects your system (99 out of 100 is does not but you do not want that 1 to happen ;)) getting your system back to the last working state is more important than to fix the problem.

> sleep 60 && sudo netplan apply && sleep 15 && sudo omd start website

This should not be needed. I would arrange this with a "service". That way you can create a chain of commands that wait for eachother.
"sleep 60" and "sleep 15"... what if it needed to be 61 and 16? Services would fix that issue for you.

> Also, is the 1,3,5 part viable? Would this restart the machine on Mo, We and Fr?

As Dan said in a comment: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#00_02_*_*_1,3,5) with your crontab rules inserted states "At 02:00 on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday."

If there is no reason for a reboot I would not execute it. I have servers running for over 5 years where once every while I clean out memory issues and the likes :+

Comment: As for mailing, it is enough that the server has an MTA installed (which should be normal for a server - at least it is in Debian, I don't know how in Ubuntu Server because i used only dekstop versions of Ubuntu). Then cron will mail automatically any output to root.

Comment: That is likely the same on Ubuntu. I know I get mails from our servers but never had to delve into the how :D

Comment: You have to install and setup an MTA (default is `postfix`) on the server, and internal mailing works "out of the box". However, if it should send to an external mail address, this needs to be configured with DKIM etc. to prevent being flagged as untrusted and/or spam.

Comment: For the absolute commands: is there an easy way to find the directories where the commands are located? I tried the man page and looked through bin & sbin but I am not really sure if I can trust my own research... The apt I found in /bin for example...
Thanks for the idea with the services, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Use the `which` command, i.e. `which apt`.

Comment: Actually, use `type`, not `which` since `type` will also resolve aliases, functions etc. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Comment: "And you should not upgrade a --production-- server unattended" security upgrades are usually not an issue, which is the default for unattended-upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everything in the other answers, but let me add this...

It is dangerous to run `apt-get` unattended.  A handful of applications ask questions during upgrades and upgrade installs, and a few others require keyboard input if you put them in the background and will hang, even though no keyboard input is needed.

Trying to run apt-get in the background like this is a good way to end up with a system where updates are broken and have to be manually configured and resumed.

The unattended-upgrades process is suppose to automatically install critical updates without intervention.

If your machine is crashing, you need to investigate why.
Perhaps run hardware diagnostics overnight.  Check logs around the time of the crash.  Maybe check if something is running it out of memory and causing the machine to freeze.  Etc...

Also, you need to run `apt autoremove` occasionally or kernel updates will collect until your disk fills up.